# JQuery Custom Animation Issue using SetInterval & SetTimeout

Tags: javascript, jquery, settimeout, setinterval

The problem I'm having is that IE and Safari (Mac OS X not Windows Version) are flickering the images during animation and sometimes not doing the animation at all. Google, Firefox, and Opera don't this issue after load. I think it's redownloading the image each time to cause the flicker.

Here's the test site: http://www.yeoworks.cz.cc/otherdomains/theoasis/

Here's the uncompressed JQuery Code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
//LOGO ANIMATION
setInterval( function(){
setTimeout(function(){
$('#logoani').css('background-image', 'url(ootr1.png)');
}, 0);
setTimeout(function(){
$('#logoani').css('background-image', 'url(ootr2.png)');
}, 200);
setTimeout(function(){
$('#logoani').css('background-image', 'url(ootr3.png)');
}, 300);
setTimeout(function(){
$('#logoani').css('background-image', 'url(ootr4.png)');
}, 400);
setTimeout(function(){
$('#logoani').css('background-image', 'url(ootr5.png)');
}, 500);
setTimeout(function(){
$('#logoani').css('background-image', 'url(ootr4.png)');
}, 600);
setTimeout(function(){
$('#logoani').css('background-image', 'url(ootr3.png)');
}, 700);
setTimeout(function(){
$('#logoani').css('background-image', 'url(ootr2.png)');
}, 800);
}, 900);
});
```

Thanks for helping :)

Comment: That was the first thing I did, but the quality SUCKS with gif. I'm trying to move away from Flash as well so the animation works in none flash devices. I can't wait for apng.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If an animated gif (even one with very little palette compression) still doesn't do the trick, I would try a different approach. This may be more trouble than it's worth to you; the bug doesn't happen for me in Safari, and I really think you can get there with a carefully compressed animated gif, but nonetheless...

Instead of changing the url of the background-image each time, perhaps IE & Safari would perform better if all the images existed on the page (positioned absolutely on top of one another), and you called `.show()` and `.hide()` respectively.

I would store all these images (or jQuery objects containing `<img>` tags) in an array, and create a function that runs every 100ms via setInterval. When it runs, `.show()` the 'next' image in the array, while telling the currently visible one to `.hide()`.

This way, you can make sure that there's always an image visible at any given moment, and there's no flicker.

Comment: Good answer! I was going to try messing the Z-Order. Thanks. This way I can keep the PNGs and they can blend in with any background I choose if I need to change the site for any reason.

Comment: ah yes, the z-order is the same basic idea =).  Good luck!

Comment: Thanks I found another way of doing it with CSS Display: None & Block.